# Evaluate another awk expression inside awk

Tags: bash, awk

In the dataset I am processing, the 5th (`$5`) column of each line contains a date in `'%d/%m/%y'` format. I want to compare this with a user provided one.

I know that in order to easily compare dates with relational binary operators they need to be in `%y-%m-%d` so I need to inline-convert the 5th columns value to that in order for the expression to evaluate to true:

Here's what I've come up with till now:

```
    awk -F "$columnsep" -v dateA="$bornsince" '{if (FNR>1 && dateA<= system("bash echo "$5"| awk -F '/' '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}'") ) {print}}' $file
```

As you can see, the `'{if (FNR>1 && dateA<= system("bash echo "$5"| awk -F '/' '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}'") ) {print}}'` is the expression I am trying to evaluate but I have trouble getting the system call to parse. I really just want to call `awk -F '/' '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}'"`, piping `$5` into it in order to convert the date properly.

- Needs to work on macos and linux (ubuntu)

Minimal example dataset:

`1099511629352  Nunez   Jorge   female  17/11/1986`

Comment: You could provide a minimal example of your dataset

Comment: awk version 20121220 on a macbook pro late 2017 up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a gawk solution

```
awk -F "$columnsep" -v dateA="$bornsince" '
    (FNR > 1 && dateA <= cnv_date($5))
    function cnv_date(date,    a) {
        split(date, a, "/")
        return a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1]
    }' $file
```